# How do you create an "empty" FitNesse site

Tags: installation, fitnesse

I'm trying to start a blank FitNesse akin to what Uncle Bob did here: http://vimeo.com/2765514

I'm using release 20100303 and I cannot find how to prevent an entire "Welcome to FitNesse" site to expand whenever I use the `-d` switch.

Here's what I'm doing on Windows:

```
java -jar fitnesse20100303/fitnesse.jar -e 0 -p 8888 -d content
```

I'm assuming this would create a 1 page site for me, not the larger site with Turtorials/Quick Starts/User Guides.

**UPDATE:** The site would have all necessary code files to function, but without the extra FitNesse-specific files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -o to prevent FitNesse from updating your site.

Comment: This is helpful, but I thought in the video he was able to create a shell of a site (with the necessary base fitnesse code, but no content).  If I try that now, I don't experience the same result.

Comment: Hmmm. You might have to let it create the 'verbose' site on first use and then delete all the stuff you don't want. Then -o should stop it from repopulating the stuff you deleted.

Comment: Has this not been fixed yet? The -o version doesn't install the basic set of files required and you just get errors about missing stuff straight away.